# I'm loosing internet conection only on chrome

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, google-chrome, dell-latitude

I have internet wifi connection working in my Dell latitude but after starting Windows (Windows 10), or after opening the laptop, the connection does not work in Chrome (Versión 74.0.3729.169 (Build official) (64 bits)).

In every other application works, but Chrome asks me to check my internet connection. I know that the connection is working because, for example, WhatsApp desktop app is able to send and receive messages, and MS OneDrive keeps in sync.

After some minutes have passed, Chrome is able to connect to the internet. I don-t know what makes the connection to work again. I've tried to restart the wifi connection, dump Chrome history, and cookies, and nothing have helped. After some minutes it just gets connected.

Chrome is updated, I don't have any plugin installed, and of course, there's no problem with the firewall since eventually Chrome gets connected. I use Avast free antivirus and don't use another firewall other than Windows firewall. No other computer or device has shown the same issue.

Comment: What is the exact message you are receiving in Chrome? Maybe post a screenshot. What other firewall / security / anti-virus software do you have installed? What other applications ARE working - how do you know? Give an example. Have you tried IE, Edge, or FireFox? Have you checked the output of `ipconfig /all` during this time of trouble? Are any other computers or devices experiencing similar issues?

Comment: "eventually Chrome gets connected." HOW does chrome eventually get connected? After a certain period of time? Is chrome running on a proxy?

Comment: @Appleoddity, I don't know what to look for in ipconfig /all output. I will publish the message as soon as I get the error.

Comment: That is why you need to [edit] and add this information to your post.

Comment: @Appleoddity Is safe to publish icongif output?

Comment: If there is something you recognize that you don't want anybody else to know, like the DNS suffix or hostname you can obfuscate it. But the IP information in the output is safe to post.